# Is there any way to salvage a broken needle (discrete form-factor, hard to replace)?

Tags: sewing, sewing-machine

My wife broke a needle, which apparently is not a conventional one you could easily buy a replacement for.  Not surprisingly, a search online reveals the general consensus would be to simply replace it, which is no help to me.  I'm pretty skeptical about any adhesive being able to hold for very long, but I was wondering if I might be able to just solder and sand it back down?  Any tips or ideas?

Comment: I am not sure that it will help, but still, a picture of the broken needle might help. Also, the dimensions of the needle are important. While some needles have a thickness of a hair, other have the thickness of a finger. Repairing those cannot be done in the same way. What material is the needle made of? Metal? Plastic? Wood?

Comment: What's special about the needle? Is it remotely possible there's a more readily available substitute?

Comment: Needles need to be smooth on the outside. Any kind of repair is likely to introduce burrs that will either cause a more rapid re-break, or damage whatever material is joined. And seconding the need for clarification on what's so special about this needle; I can't imagine any kind of needle that's so special it would need a repair.

Comment: Please provide more information about the machine make and model and what the needle’s special purpose/function is, such as it’s a double needle or it has a special eye. A picture would be very helpful as well. Needles for a sewing machine should not be repaired they should only be replaced as they wear down.

Comment: @virolino yes, a picture would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most sewing needles are steel of some sort (possibly stainless), which doesn't solder with ordinary electronics or plumbing methods. If you have the kit and experience, it might be possible to braze the steel, but only if the break is in the right place. You need somewhere to build up material, so you can't treat it like superglue. You could of course file away material before and after.

If it's a fairly big needle and I was desperate, I'd make a jig to hold it (clamping a cork to the machine should do) and use a very little bit of slow epoxy between the broken faces. Look for one that tells you not to handle the part for several hours, and pay attention to the "full strength is reached in" instruction. You may be able to build up the join on the outside afterwards.  This might be enough to finish the job, but it's unlikely to be a long term fix.